# res.send() not returning anything

Tags: node.js, express, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am using the Vimeo library to display a specific video.

My Node.js code:

```
app.get("/video/:id", (req, res) => {
    client.request(
    {
        method: "GET",
        path: `/videos/${req.params.id}`,
    },
    (error, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        res.send(body.data);
    });
});
```

`console.log()` before `res.send()` displays the object perfectly but does not send it, even though I get 200 response, the body is completely empty.

Comment: what body are you trying to return? its a get request either you would be sending a HTML page or a json data.
before res.send, try console.log ( body.data) if that's empty that means there is is nothing in the body.data

Comment: As I mentioned, I did console.log(body.data) before res.send() and it does display the object perfectly, but when I send it, POSTMAN or my front end does not display anything.

Comment: in your codeconsole.log is mention under if statement :),anyways  it should be `req,body.data`